# Не удается использовать dll с CUDA в C#

Tags: c#, dll, cuda

Была произведена попытка запустить из C# dll с CUDA-программой.

Код C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace testdllproject
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("asdf.dll", EntryPoint = "main")]
        public static extern IntPtr DisplayHelloFromDll();

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is C# program.");
            Console.WriteLine(DisplayHelloFromDll());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

  }
}
```

Код asdf.dll:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void kernel(void) {
}

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int main(void) {
        kernel <<< 1, 1 >>>();
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Все это компилируется, но при запуске, на строке

```
Console.WriteLine(DisplayHelloFromDll());
```

вылетает [AccessViolationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) и говорит: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."

Как лечить?

Comment: почему у вас `DllImport` объявлен с возвращаемым типом `IntPtr`? почему не просто int, у вас ведь из нативной части функция возвращает не указатель. Если поменять на `int` в `DllImport`, такая же ошибка будет?

Comment: `kernel << < 1, 1 >> >()` - это что вообще за синтаксис такой?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, да, если поменять на int в DllImport, такая же ошибка будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так скопировалось почему-то.

Comment: Ну так поправьте.

Comment: @c47harsis проверьте, что разрядность собранной библиотеки совпадает с разрядностью запускаемого приложения. Проверьте, что выключен флаг `Prefer32` в настройках проекта, если вы запускаете на 64-битной системе.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, спасибо, дело продвинулось, можно сказать, когда снял галочку Prefer32 с проекта C#. Теперь происходит такое: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe

Additional information: Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007000B)` на той же строке.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, изменил разрядность библиотеки на x64, снова кидает AccessViolationException на той же строке. :(